Unit tests to verify override methods with generic parameters
I am trying to add tests to verify the functionality of a derived class overridden method with generics, but I just cannot get it to work. I've tried using a spy as well as partial mocks. I want to verify the functionality as well as ensure that the base class is also invoked.
The base class is in a different library and I cannot change that. :(
The code is written in Kotlin and I am using JUnit5 and Mockito.
open class BaseClass<T> {
    open fun doSomething(data: T): String {
        return "Base result"
    }
}

class DerivedClass<T> : BaseClass<T>() {
    override fun doSomething(data: T): String {
        val preprocessedData = preprocess(data)
        return super.doSomething(preprocessedData)
    }

    fun preprocess(data: T): T {
        // Preprocessing logic
        return data
    }
}

Tests:
@Test
fun `test using spy`() {
    val derivedClassSpy = spy(DerivedClass<String>())
    doReturn("processed").`when`(derivedClassSpy).preprocess("data")
    doReturn("Mocked base upload").`when`(derivedClassSpy as BaseClass<String>).upload("processed")

    val result = derivedClassSpy.upload("data")
    verify(derivedClassSpy).preprocess("data")
    verify(derivedClassSpy as BaseClass<String>).upload("processed")
    assertThat(result, equalTo("Mocked base upload"))
}

@Test
fun `test partial mock`() {
    val derivedClassSpy = spy(DerivedClass<String>())
    doReturn("processed").`when`(derivedClassSpy).preprocess("data")
    doReturn("Mocked base upload").`when`(derivedClassSpy as BaseClass<String>).upload("processed")

    val result = derivedClassSpy.upload("data")
    verify(derivedClassSpy).preprocess("data")
    verify(derivedClassSpy as BaseClass<String>).upload("processed")
    assertThat(result, equalTo("Mocked base upload"))
}

